# How can I fix this vs10 inconsistent dll linkage warning?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, warnings

I have a series of warnings that I'm trying to fix when building [gdcm](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gdcm/index.php?title=Main_Page) using visual studio 10 (32 bit version):

```
4>..\..\..\..\gdcm\Utilities\gdcmexpat\lib\xmlparse.c(647): warning C4273: 'XML_ParserCreate' : inconsistent dll linkage
4>          d:\src\gdcm\gdcm\utilities\gdcmexpat\lib\expat.h(206) : see previous definition of 'XML_ParserCreate'
```

The function call itself looks like:

```
XML_Parser XMLCALL
XML_ParserCreate(const XML_Char *encodingName)
{
   return XML_ParserCreate_MM(encodingName, NULL, NULL);
}
```

where

```
#define XMLCALL __cdecl
```

and

```
XMLPARSEAPI(XML_Parser)
XML_ParserCreate(const XML_Char *encoding);
```

where

```
#define XMLPARSEAPI(type) XMLIMPORT type XMLCALL
```

and

```
#define XMLIMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
```

If I'm reading that properly, that means that the linkage is consistently __cdecl through XMLCALL-- right?  Because, if so, then the warning is superfluous, or am I misinterpreting this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it is complaining about `__declspec(dllimport)` missing from the function definition but present on the function declaration.  You ought to take this seriously, it doesn't make sense to declare the function imported from a DLL but *also* present in your code.  You can't have it both ways.

This is usually caused by a missing #define.  You edited down the macro definitions, I think, but when building the DLL you usually specify a macro in the build command (/D).  So that the declaration of the function uses dllexport instead of dllimport.  Which ensures that the function gets exported from the DLL.  The client code uses the same .h file but is built without that macro defined.  It sees the function declared as dllimport.

Take a closer look at the XMLIMPORT macro definition, `__declspec(dllexport)` should be close.  Another diagnostic is the set the exported functions, visible with Dumpbin.exe /exports.  They should be missing if I guessed correctly.

Comment: That was it-- that dllimport should have been a dllexport.

Comment: Wow, I missed one too with a variable being exported. In the header I had something like `COMMON_API extern const std::string   someStr;` while in the cpp file I had `const std::string   someStr("Background");` which was missing the export/import specifier. The API macro changes teams based on whether the project has a macro defined telling it to be a dll build or not. I'll have to keep an eye on this one.