# Writing a DLL correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, coding-style

I'm still not completely sure about how to write correcly a DLL in Visual Studio.

file .h

```
#ifndef UPLOAD_H_
# define UPLOAD_H_

# ifdef UPLOAD_EXPORT
#  define UPLOAD_API __declspec(dllimport)
# else
#  define UPLOAD_API __declspec(dllexport)
# endif // UPLOAD_EXPORT

#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinInet.h>

extern "C" UPLOAD_API int uploadFTP(
    const char *...,
    const char *...,
    const char *...,
    const char *...,
    const char *...,
    const char *...);

#endif // UPLOAD_H_
```

file .cpp

```
#include "upload.h"

extern "C" UPLOAD_API int uploadFTP(
    const char *...,
    const char *...,
    const char *...,
    const char *...,
    const char *...,
    const char *...)
{
  ...
}
```

This actually works but on MSDN thay write on the .h file:

```
#ifdef MATHFUNCSDLL_EXPORTS
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif
```

That is actually the opposite of what I'm doing, and they do not specify MATHFUNCSDLL_API on the functions of .cpp file.

**EDIT:**

Solution -> UPLOAD_EXPORT was not correctly defined under Project Properties/C++/Preprocessor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#define` statements in MSDN's .h file are the correct ones. You define `UPLOAD_EXPORTS` when building the DLL, so all UPLOAD_API functions will be declared as `dllexport`. You don't define it anywhere else, so all clients will see them as `dllimport`.

**PS:** You may want to declare your functions `WINAPI` as well (it means `__stdcall`) if you wish to use them from languages other than C and C++. Note however that using `dllexport` instead of a .def file exports the function names with call-convention-specific decorations (leading underscore, etc.)

Comment: What doy you say about how they define the functions on MSDN?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms235636.aspx

Comment: @Medinoc "You don't define it anywhere else.." - What about the .def file, is it then redundant?

Comment: I'm not sure it's important to specify MYDLL_API on both declaration and definition. But I think doing both doesn't hurt and is more readable.

Comment: @fiscblog the .def file is an alternate way to export functions without using __declspec. Unusable (to my knowledge) with C++ classes, but makes easier-to-use DLLs when used to export C functions.

Comment: if I do as MSDN says, I get warning C4273: 'uploadFTP' : inconsistent dll linkage

Comment: Check that you rebuilt all and that UPLOAD_API is defined in the project options for the whole DLL project.

Comment: I remember this [warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dt1zk962%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) LNK4197. It worked out anyway, but nevertheless it's a warning..

Comment: I was reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341661/how-can-i-fix-this-vs10-inconsistent-dll-linkage-warning 
And they say that dllimport should have been dllexport

Comment: Wait, do you get the warning when compiling the DLL or the client? (A)DLL --> there's a dllimport remaining somewhere, should get rid of it. (B)Client --> Seems that you included the function definition in your client, should get rid of it.

Comment: Got it! The preprocessor directive under Project Properties was not correct!